# jquery checkboxes uncheck issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a script that loads from a db an array of numbners and select those checkboxes that correspond. Numbers in array are between 1 and 43 and i have 43 checkboxes from id="1" to id="43".
The script is triggered from a select.

```
function getroleitems(ruolo){
    fun = new Array();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {id: ruolo},
    url: "getroleitems.php",
    success: function(data){
        fun = data;
        if (fun.length){ 
        $('#' + fun.join(', #')).attr('checked', true);
        }
    },dataType:"json"
    });

};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ruolo').change(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    var ruolo=$('#ruolo').val();
    getroleitems(ruolo);
    });
});
```

The issue is that if I add this line:

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

the script doesn't flag anymore the checkboxes. I have tried to add this line both in the change function and inside the ajax one with the same luck. 
I need to reset the status of each checkbox to unset before loading the new array. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try this: `$('input:checkbox').each(function(){this.checked = false; });`

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting the same result. The code trows no error, get into the the if(fun.length) loop but doesn't check any box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
The point is that with .attr() you set the value of an attribute in the DOM tree. Depending on the browser, browser version and jQuery version (especially 1.7), this does not always have the desired effect.

With .prop(), you manipulate the property (in this case, 'checked state').

So as I changed

```
$('#' + fun.join(', #')).attr('checked', true);
```

to use .prop instead of .attr

```
$('#' + fun.join(', #')).prop('checked', true);
```

the code started showing everything correctly.
Note that whithout this line

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

.attr() and .prop() give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

or:

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: Same luck, already tried. The code doesn't work even for the first execution (when I load the page for the first time).

Comment: Goran, the code itself works. But the point is that it gets into the the if(fun.length) loop but doesn't check any box. W/o this line everything works fine.

Comment: Check your dynamic selector .. just to be sure : console.log( '#' + fun.join(', #') ); Obviously there is an error laying around somewhere, so best bet is to go trough function step by step

Comment: All the code works fine. It stops working ONLY if I add the instruction to first uncheck the boxes

Answer (score 0):

For attributes which have underlying boolean properties (of which checked is one), `removeAttr` automatically sets the underlying property to false. (Note that this is among the backwards-compatibility "fixes" added in jQuery 1.6.1).you can use:

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```